# How do I replace all instances of prices (beginning with "US$") in html page using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

Say I have the following HTML:

```
<div class="L-shaped-icon-container">
  <span class="L-shaped-icon">Something is US$50.25 and another thing is US$10.99.</span>
</div>
```

What I'd like to do is replace all instances of **US$XX.xx** with **GBP£YY.yy** on the live page using jquery.

The value of GBP would be determined by my own currency conversion ratio.

So I'm assuming what I'd first need to do is use a regular expression to get all instances of the prices which would be anything beginning with **USD$** and ending after **.xx**? Prices will always have cents displayed.

Then I'm stuck what would be the best way to accomplish  the next part.

Should I wrap these instances in a span tag with a class, then use jquery.each() function to loop through each and replace the contents with a jquery(this).html("GBP£YY.yy")?

Any help setting me on the right path would be greatly appreciated. Thanks guys.

Comment: I think you will need to call a `replace()` with the `/\bUS\$(\d+\.\d+)/g` regex and then perform all the operations with the price inside the callback (e.g. `return "GBP" + toGBP(m[1]);` where `toGBP` is the converter function).

Comment: You also could use split and indexOf instead of regex and either the `$('*')` selector or `$('p, span,...')` to target all tags which cold hold prices. Also it is important to figure out if there are instances of US$ which shall remain unchanged or whether the number format could be different between instances.

Comment: its kind of sad that you never gave a response nor did you accept an answer.

Answer (score 0):

base method for text replacements:

```
var textWalker = function (node, callback) {
    var nodes = [node];
    while (nodes.length > 0) {
        node = nodes.shift();
        for (var i = 0; i < node.childNodes.length; i++) {
            var child = node.childNodes[i];
            if (child.nodeType === child.TEXT_NODE)
                callback(child);
            else
                nodes.push(child);
        }
    }
};
```

stuff you need to do:

```
var USDinGBP = 0.640573954;
textWalker(document, function (n) {
    n.nodeValue = n.nodeValue.replace(/(USD?\$(\d+(\.\d+)?))/g, function($0, $1, $2){
        return "GBP£" + (parseFloat($2) * USDinGBP).toFixed(2);
    })
})
```

you can fire that on ANY site. it will even replace titles etc.

so.. to tell you about the benefits of not using jquery for this:
jquery will process and wrap every single element in a browser compatible way.
using a native javascript solution would speed up this process alot.
using native textnodes also is benefitial since it will not break event handlers for child elements.

you should also consider using [fastdom](https://github.com/wilsonpage/fastdom).
it does not matter if you are using jquery or native js. after writing to elements the dom has to do certain tasks before it can be read again. in the end you will loose some time for each edited element.

to give you a fastdom example:

```
var textWalker = function (node, callback) {
    var nodes = [node];
    while (nodes.length > 0) {
        node = nodes.shift();
        for (var i = 0; i < node.childNodes.length; i++) {
            var child = node.childNodes[i];
            if (child.nodeType === child.TEXT_NODE)
                callback(child);
            else
                nodes.push(child);
        }
    }
};

var textReplace = function (node, regex, callback) {
    textWalker(node, function (n) {
        fastdom.read(function () {
            var text = n.nodeValue;
            if (!regex.test(text)) {
                return;
            }
            text = text.replace(regex, callback);
            fastdom.write(function () {
                n.nodeValue = text;
            });
        });
    });
};

// put this function call into your onload function:
var USDinGBP = 0.640573954;
textReplace(document, /(USD?\$(\d+(\.\d+)?))/g, function($0, $1, $2){
    return "GBP£" + (parseFloat($2) * USDinGBP).toFixed(2);
});
```

this will basically do the job in an instant.

if you want to go even further you could add this to jquery as following:

```
jQuery.fn.textReplace = function (regex, callback) {
    this.each(function () {
        textReplace(this, regex, callback);
    });
};
```

and call it like that:

```
var USDinGBP = 0.640573954;

jQuery(".L-shaped-icon").textReplace(/(USD?\$(\d+(\.\d+)?))/g, function($0, $1, $2){
    return "GBP£" + (parseFloat($2) * USDinGBP).toFixed(2);
});
```

Answer (score -1):

If all of these values are directly in the span, if not you can give them a unique class and use it to iterate over them, you can use the following

1. You first get the numeric part of the string in a variable
2. convert the currency store it in other variable.
3. replace US$ with GBP
4. replace numeric part of the string with converted value

jQuery:

```
("span").each(function() { 
     var currencyVal=$(this).text().match(/\d/);
     var convertedVal=currencyVal * 100;      // just for example.
     $(this).text($(this).text().replace(/^US$/,'GBP£'));
     $(this).text($(this).text().replace(/\d/,convertedVal));

 });
```

Comment: Doesn't this also change values which aren't lead by US$?

Comment: You can give a unique class to all the span's congaing these values. It assumes that <span> only has the value which needs to be converted.

Comment: @user3154108 yep it does. well.. i've added a proper solution now.

Answer (score -1):

I hope this will helps you. Here is working **[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2auwg1qy/2/)**

**HTML:**

```
<div class="L-shaped-icon-container">
  <span class="L-shaped-icon">Something is US$50.25 and another thing is US$10.99.</span>
  <span class="L-shaped-icon">Something is BR$20.25 and another thing is US$10.99.</span>
  <span class="L-shaped-icon">Something is US$10.25 and another thing is US$10.99.</span>
  <span class="L-shaped-icon">Something is US$50.20 and another thing is GR$10.99.</span>    
</div>

<button class="btnUpdate">Update</button>
```

**JavaScript Code:**

```
function UpdateCurrency(){

var UStoGB=10;
$('span').each(function(e){

    var matchedText = $(this).text().match(/US\$\S+/g);
    var updatedText = $(this).text();
    if(matchedText){        
        for(var i=0;i<= matchedText.length;i++){

            if(matchedText[i]){            
                var currentValue=matchedText[i].replace('US$','');            
                if(!currentValue) currentValue=0;        
                var newCurrency = ( parseFloat(currentValue) * UStoGB);

                updatedText= updatedText.replace(matchedText[i],'GBP£'+newCurrency);            
            }        
        }        
    }

    $(this).text(updatedText);
});
return false;
}
```