# HTML DOM how to optimize this code?

Tags: javascript, html

I got this code:

```
allNodes = document.getElementsByTagName("*");
for (node in allNodes) {
    if (allNodes[node].innerHTML != undefined) {
        allNodes[node].innerHTML = allNodes[node].innerHTML.replace('adshss sd', '1fsss');
        allNodes[node].innerHTML = allNodes[node].innerHTML.replace('adsss sd', '1fsss');
        allNodes[node].innerHTML = allNodes[node].innerHTML.replace('addsss sd', '1fsss');
        allNodes[node].innerHTML = allNodes[node].innerHTML.replace('adfsss sd', '1fsss');
    }
}
```

I have 10 different lines where I replace text in the for loop and I have noticed that it takes a whole lot of time to complete, so my question is: How can I optimize this? The goal is to find the text on the website (the elements are not named of anything and are all `<td>`) and then replace it.

I know by experiece that it is way quicker if you then know the index number for the element holding the specific text that you want to replace but that it really hard to find here when there are more than 200 elements.
Thanks!

Comment: you are doing it wrong. by overriding innerHTML you essentially destroy node references and event listeners. you'd want to use textContent instead. well.. its more complicated than that. you have to grab all TextNodes and throw it at them.

Comment: Maybe ask here:
http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/ask

Comment: just figured i made something similar in the past. though you have to dig through it yourself: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31851180/how-do-i-replace-all-instances-of-prices-beginning-with-us-in-html-page-usi/31852811#31852811

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that your markup doesn't have this input value (`"adsss sd"`) as the attribute value as well, try this

Since you are replacing a simple text rather than a markup,

```
document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace( /adsss sd/g, '1fsss');
```

Comment: This is a much faster solution than iterating over each node, but be sure to keep in mind the [security concerns](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML#Security_considerations) - don't let someone splice an XSS attack into your page!

Comment: Yes off course, if the value you are replacing your input with is entered by user, then all sort of issues can happen

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer! But how does it work in the same way as my code?

Comment: @sostack I didn't get your question. Can you rephrase the same?

Comment: @gurvinder372, of course. How can that single statement change severals elements? Doesn't it only change one element's text? and what is the g for?

Comment: @sostack `g` is for global `replace`. yes, it will replace the text in the entire html inside the `body`

Answer (score 0):

```
  var allNodes = document.getElementsByTagName("*");
  [].forEach.call(allNodes, function(node) {
    node.innerHTML = node.innerHTML.replace('adsss sd', '1fsss');
  });
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.