# How to change color of specific text inside html element pre?

Tags: javascript, colors

I want a code snippet that will search for a keyword text inside HTML element -  pre -> code and replace the color of all occurrences of those keywords.

For example, If my text inside pre contains a text - SET, I want to replace it with red color.

I have tried a few codes but it just prints "externalHtml" in red color.

Also, what will be the efficient way to write this code. I may have around 10 to 15 of those keywords and I want to change all of those to just one color. There is no other group of keywords or colors.

```js
var keyword = document.getElementsByClassName('language-sas');
var externalHtml = '<span style="color:red">'+keyword[0]+'</span>'
    keyword[0].innerHTML = keyword[0].innerHTML.replace('set',externalHtml ); 

/*
code.html(code.html().replace(/set/, ' <
  span style = "color: red" > $ & < /span>'
));


}
*/
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>


</head>

<body>

  <pre class="language-sas1">
<code class=" language-sas">
<span class="token keyword">data</span> keep_vars <span class="token punctuation">;</span>
    <span class="t">set</span> sashelp<span class="token punctuation">.</span>citimon<span class="token punctuation">;</span>
   </div></div></pre>

</body>

</html>
```

Any thoughts or suggestions will be really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Whatever you have written is mostly correct. You forgot to write `.innerHTML` in second line of your JS code.

```
var externalHtml = '<span style="color:red">'+keyword[0].innerHTML+'</span>'
```

Answer (score 0):

#### I avoid using innerHTML when ever possible.

I've made something similar before for a relatable question:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/31852811/1519836

You could adapt it to your problem like this:

```js
// This function will allow you to process DOM Trees
// and run a defined function on each Node.
const textWalker = function (node, callback) {
  const nodes = [node];
  while (nodes.length > 0) {
    node = nodes.shift();
    const children = [...node.childNodes];
    for (let i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
      var child = children[i];
      if (child.nodeType === HTMLElement.TEXT_NODE)
        callback(child);
      else
        nodes.push(child);
    }
  }
};

// This will run a callback for each text node matching a given regexp pattern
// The callback function can return an array of elements and strings.
// The callback return value will be constructed in DOM
const textSplit = function (source, regexp, callback) {
  textWalker(source, function (node) {
    let text = node.nodeValue;
    
    if (!regexp.test(text)) {
      return;
    }
    
    const out = callback(regexp, text);
    
    if (!(out instanceof Array)) {
      node.nodeValue = ""+out;
    }
    else {
      let nnode = out.shift();

      if (nnode instanceof HTMLElement || nnode.nodeType === HTMLElement.TEXT_NODE) {
        // Doesn't work with text nodes yet: node.insertAdjacentElement("afterend", nnode);
        node.parentNode.insertBefore(nnode, node);
        node.parentNode.removeChild(node);
        node = nnode;
      }
      else {
        node.textContent = ""+nnode;
      }

      while (out.length > 0) {
        nnode = out.shift();
        
        if (!(nnode instanceof HTMLElement) && nnode.nodeType !== HTMLElement.TEXT_NODE) {
          nnode = document.createTextNode(""+nnode);
        }
        // Doesn't work with text nodes yet: node.insertAdjacentElement("afterend", nnode);
        node.parentNode.insertBefore(nnode, node);
        node.parentNode.insertBefore(node, nnode);
        
        node = nnode;
      }
    }
  });
};

// put this function call into your onload function:
const template = document.createElement("span");
template.style.color = "red";

// You could obviously simplify any of this how ever you want.
textSplit(document.querySelector("pre"), /(set)/g, function(regexp, text) {
  const out = [];
  text.split(regexp).forEach((text, i) => {
    if (i % 2 === 0) {
      out.push(text);
      return;
    };

    const node = template.cloneNode(true);
    node.textContent = text;

    out.push(node);
  });
  return out;
});
```

```html
<pre class="language-sas1">
<code class=" language-sas">
<span class="token keyword">data</span> keep_vars <span class="token punctuation">;</span>
<span class="t">set</span> sashelp<span class="token punctuation">.</span>citimon<span class="token punctuation">;</span>
</div></div></pre>
```

Maybe one day I extend this past one text node barrier.
For now you can only use it for self contained text nodes.

Alternatively you could also execute color calls on selected text through the contentEditable stuff.
I'd recommend using an editor for that tho.